# How to create a custom Helm chart that basically just sets values of another chart?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-helm

I'm new to Helm and I haven't quite fully grasped the concepts yet. What I'm currently trying to do is to create a custom chart that basically just sets specific values for another chart that's available in the default stable repository. Pretty much what I want to do is have this:

```
helm install \
-f my-custom-values.yaml \
stable/target-chart \
--name=my-release
```

changed into

```
helm install my-apps/my-release
```

With `my-release` using the same values in `my-custom-values.yaml`. It's essentially bundling the pre-existent chart into a new one with my custom values.

Is there a way to do this? I think I might be able to clone the source chart, but I don't feel like that's a practical thing to do.

Comment: I didn’t really understand your question, but I dare to suggest - look at for flag: --reuse-values

Answer (score 2):

What is the issue with the first variation? If you have a custom values.yaml that you can pass to helm why do you need to remove it from the command line?

But if you are ready to play around a bit... :)

One way of doing this would be creating your own chart, that will be mainly empty but consist of a requirements.yaml that refers to `stable/target-chart`.

requirements.yaml (just beside Chart.yaml)

```
dependencies:
  - name: stable/target-chart
    version: 1.0.0.0.0.0
    alias: somealiasforvaluesyaml
```

In your values.yaml you then overwrite the values of that sub-chart:

```
somealiasforvaluesyaml:
  keyfromthattargetchart: newvalue

  subkeyfromthattargetchart:
    enabled: true
    setting: "value"
```

The alias you give in the requirements.yaml is the section in your values.yaml from your chart.

Before installing you need to tell helm to update these requirements:

```
helm repo update
helm dependency update
```

and then just `helm install` this (virtual?) chart. This chart does not contain any resources to it would not be called a package in linux package managers - but they also use transitional packages or packages that just are a collection of others (like the build-essential)

Considering you already have the values.yaml to overwrite the ones in the target-chart this is all a bit much? Since the cust-values .yaml to pass to install with `-f` just needs to contain the customization as it will ammend the values.yaml from the target-chart your first command in the question looks like the correct way to go.